# Match three columns in two excel sheets and fetch fourth column if it matches

Tags: excel

I've two excel sheets.

Sheet-1 contains columns as follows

UserId,mobile1,mobile2.

Sheet-2 contains columns as follows
UserId,mobile1,mobile2,username.

I've to match userid,mobile1,mobile2 if it matches get username in another cell in sheet1.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Sheet2` is as follows

[image]

Then in `Cell D2` of `Sheet1` enter the following formula

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$10,SUMPRODUCT((A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10)*(B2=Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10)*(C2=Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10)*(ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10)-1)))
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

Comment: @S.TATHITHIYAN - `not giving correct result` what exactly is the problem? Can you share the screen shot of your data.